# CKQuery Comparing Dates returns empty array

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckquery

I am attempting to query a CloudKit private database by comparing two date fields.

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timeStamp == %@", parcoursTimeStamp as CVarArg)
            let query = CKQuery(recordType: "ParcoursRecord", predicate: predicate)
            privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: recordZone.zoneID, completionHandler: { (result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error querying for record: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("Query result: \(result)")
                }

        })
```

I only receive Query result: Optional([ ]) but never any results although I know the timeStamps I am comparing are the same. What am I doing wrong? Is the predicate defined incorrectly (which would be me guess)?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you `timestamp` CKRecord type has been defined as `NSDate`...

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timeStamp ==  %@", parcoursTimeStamp  as NSDate)
```